# Vue template use JavaScript build-in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates

How can I use JavaScript build-in function in the Vue template?

```
{{ eval(item.value.substring(2)) }}
```

I want to use JS function eval() in {{}}, but it shows many error like:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "eval" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.eval is not a function"

vue.esm.js?efeb:1906 TypeError: _vm.eval is not a function
```

Comment: Try calling eval in your component code instead, then use the result in your template code.

Comment: I know I can call it in the method, but I want to try to use JavaScript function directly in the template.

Comment: But why? Given that it is bad practice to run computations inside render code?

Comment: I just don't want to add more lines in my code. I like short code.

Comment: Use computed properties like the docs suggest. It's good practice and will keep your template code short.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to execute `eval` inside template which causes `vue` to execute `eval` method of your current component. If you want to use result of the global `eval` function in template just create a variable in your component's `data` object and store result in here. Also you can create a `computed` property with `eval` call in it and use this property inside template.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is really bad practice to use `eval` at almost any case (99.9%).

Secondly, if you really want to use it, I think you need to access `window` object, like answered there [How to access the window object in vue js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166847/how-to-access-the-window-object-in-vue-js)

And then do something like this:

```js
methods: {
 eval(expr){ return window.eval(expr) }
}
```

After that, `eval` become visible in template.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the template, Vue will prefix everything with a 'this.' Therefore it's not possible.

The most simple solution is to move it to the methods section of your Vue component.

EDIT: A horribly beautiful workaround that is inspired by @Mikhail Semikolenov answer would be to just create a computed property for the window object. Then you can call the eval (and any other window function) with:

```
{window.eval(...)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
<template>
...
{{ item }}
...
</template>

<script>
//...
data(){
  return {
    item: "oldVal"
  }
},
methods: {
   myFunc(){
     this.item = eval(item.value.substring(2)) //<-- here
   }  
}
//...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, you don't really need to use `eval()`
just call a method in your template as below:

```
<template>
    ...
    {{subItNow(item.value)}}
</template>
```

and the method should return like this :

```
methods: {
   subItNow(value){
        return value.substring(2)
    } 
}
```

or if you still want to use `eval` anyway just pass the result as a return in method functions